# convertion of jquery .one() function don't trigger in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert this piece of code, in DOM, from jQuery to standard JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main').addClass('slide-out').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
        $('#gut').addClass('overflow-hidden');
    });
});
```

and I've done this:

```
var main = document.getElementById('main');
var gut = document.getElementById('gut');
main.classList.add('slide-out');

main.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd',listener);
main.addEventListener('otransitionend',listener);
main.addEventListener('oTransitionEnd',listener);
main.addEventListener('msTransitionEnd',listener);
main.addEventListener('transitionend',listener);

var listener = function(){
    gut.classList.add('overflow-hidden');

   //also tried it, without results
    main.removeEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd',listener);
    main.removeEventListener('otransitionend',listener);
    main.removeEventListener('oTransitionEnd',listener);
    main.removeEventListener('msTransitionEnd',listener);
    main.removeEventListener('transitionend',listener);

}
```

but, unfortunately, seems that no one of these events don't trigger in JS.
There is another way to do this? I've found other guides but they again use this way to convert the code.

Thanks

Comment: *"...in vanilla JS..."* => *"...using the DOM directly..."* The **language** is the same in both cases, and no more vanilla in one case or the other.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code above that attempts to remove the handler the first time it's called, which is what jQuery's `one` does...?

Comment: Or for this simple use case just check if that class already exists

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). Also, please make sure what your question is about. Is it about doing `one` with the DOM? Or about `transitionend`. Or...?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOM has no built-in `one` analogue. Instead, you have to remove the event handler yourself:

```
var main = document.getElementById('main');
var gut = document.getElementById('gut');
main.classList.add('slide-out');

main.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd',listener);
main.addEventListener('otransitionend',listener);
main.addEventListener('oTransitionEnd',listener);
main.addEventListener('msTransitionEnd',listener);
main.addEventListener('transitionend',listener);

var listener = function(){
    gut.classList.add('overflow-hidden');
    main.removeEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd',listener);
    main.removeEventListener('otransitionend',listener);
    main.removeEventListener('oTransitionEnd',listener);
    main.removeEventListener('msTransitionEnd',listener);
    main.removeEventListener('transitionend',listener);
}
```

Comment: I've added also removeEventListener to every element, but it doesn't work, seems that event doesn't trigger

Comment: @ste9206 - That's a completely different thing from the question you asked about `one`. Have you looked at the several questions about transition end events here on SO?

Comment: Yes, I've looked much times and the major part of the solution reports your answer above..